# calling class-specific operator new

Tags: c++, memory

The expression `operator new(sizeof(T))` allocates `T` bytes via `::operator new`, correct?

Is there any way to call the class-specific version of `operator new` *if it exists*, exactly the way how `new T()` allocates memory (before calling the constructor)?

`T::operator new(sizeof(T))` gives a compile-time error if `T` does not define `operator new`, even if `T` inherits from a base class that defines it. What I would like to call is:

- `Foo::operator new` if `Foo` defines `operator new`
- `Base::operator new` if `Foo` derives from `Base` that defines `operator new` (what do I do about multiple inheritance?)
- `::operator new` otherwise

Comment: Why do you need to call it explicitly?  If operator `new` is overloaded for a class, the compiler will use it whenever you instantiate that object with `new ClassName`.

Comment: @Ama: Because I don't want to instantiate objects. I only want the memory, so I can use placement-new at a later point in time.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Surely if you are separating the allocation of memory from the construction of the object you can allocate the memory in any way that you see fit? Why do you need to allocate memory in the same way that `new T` would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library solves this problem using an allocator object whose type is set as a template parameter of the class that needs a customizable allocation algorithm.

I don't think there's any complete way to do what you asked, as already evidenced by your second bullet. There's no way for the compiler to know which parent's operator new to use if they both defined one.

If you're trying to implement for example a small object allocator pool that picks an appropriate size/pool at compile time, what about using a standalone template allocator function: It would be called something like `object_allocator<T>::allocate()` and the template type would let you figure out the size automatically. You still can't inherit operator new because of the multiple inheritance issue but it makes it easy to figure out how to allocate memory within any class.

Answer (score 0):

Define a differ static function `allocate` and call this function from `T::operator new`

```
class X {
public:
    static void * allocate(size_t size) {
           //...
    }
    void *operator new(size_t size) {
       return allocate(size);
    }
};

void f() {
   void * p = X::allocate(sizeof(X));
   X * x = new(p) X;
}
```

Comment: That solution is too intrusive for my taste :(